# How do I tell ivy4r to stay offline?

Tags: ivy, buildr

We recently switched from Ant to Buildr for building our projects. We use Ivy for dependency management, using the ivy4r Buildr extension. We have a local repository at the office which is used as a cache for public artifacts and in which we also publish our own artifacts.

Now for the problem: I'd like to be able to build my project when I do not have access to the office repository. Buildr has a flag to tell it to work offline (`-o`), but ivy4r does not seem to take this into account. Is there any way to make Ivy not try to download artifacts? I have them all available in the cache on my machine already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Setting the cache timeout to eternal

You can set the [cache](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches/cache.html) property ${ivy.cache.ttl.default} to eternal this will set the [TTL](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches/ttl.html): so that the repository will not be checked for new revisions.

You could achieve this by calling ant with the following parameter:

```
ant -Divy.cache.ttl.default=eternal build
```

This is from the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches/ttl.html):

> Defines a TTL (Time To Live) rule for resolved revision caching. When
>   Ivy resolves a dynamic version constraint (like latest.integration or
>   a version range), it can store the result of the resolution (like
>   latest.integration=1.5.1) for a given time, called TTL. It means that
>   Ivy will reuse this dynamic revision resolution result without
>   accessing the repositories for the duration of the TTL, unless running
>   resolve in refresh mode.
>
> ...
>
> The TTL duration can also be set to 'eternal', in which case once
>   resolved the revision is always use, except when resolving in refresh
>   mode.

Other references:

- [IVY-879 Implementation of this feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-879)

#### Setting UseCacheOnly for the resolve task

The [resolve task](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html) has the attribute `useCacheOnly`, which can be used to

> force[s] the resolvers to only use their caches and not their actual
>   contents

Example:

```
<ivy:resolve file="path/to/ivy.xml" useCacheOnly="true/>
```

Comment: I hadn't searched in this direction. Will try it out and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: At first glance, this works. But we have changing artifacts. Any idea on how to not go to the network for them?

Comment: Publish them to the local filesystem and retrieve from there by using the filesystem resolver.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing. Based on the offline flag, we adjust the ivy4r settings to use a different resolver chain.

Comment: For TTL to be in effect, don't forget to set your resolver's `checkmodified` attribute to `false`. I've spent hours trying to figure out why it's not working. See [this](http://grokbase.com/t/ant/ivy-user/101kyk49na/ttl-not-applied-when-using-resolver-attributes-changingrevision-or-checkmodified) for more details.