# Resolving Apache Ivy dependencies when offline/disconnected?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

How can I get Ivy to resolve dependencies (including dependencies with `changing="true"`) from the local cache when offline/disconnected?

I'm working on a Java-based open-source project that uses Apache Ivy to resolve and download 3rd party dependencies.  The project's `build.xml` has an ant target named `resolve` that downloads Ivy (if needed) and then uses Ivy to retrieve the required jars.

Everything works great when online.  However, without Internet access, `ant resolve` fails even if the required jars are in the local Ivy cache (`~/.ivy2/cache`).  It appears that Ivy is trying to connect to the Maven repository to refresh `changing="true"` dependencies.

The error I get is similar to the following:

```
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]  Host repo.example.com not found. url=http://repo.example.com/exampleorg/examplename/examplerev/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]  Host repo.example.com not found. url=http://repo.example.com/exampleorg/examplename/examplerev/jars/examplename.jar
[ivy:retrieve]          module not found: exampleorg#examplename;examplerev
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== local: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    ~/.ivy2/local/exampleorg/examplename/examplerev/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact exampleorg#examplename;examplerev!examplename.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    ~/.ivy2/local/exampleorg/examplename/examplerev/jars/examplename.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== shared: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    ~/.ivy2/shared/exampleorg/examplename/examplerev/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact exampleorg#examplename;examplerev!examplename.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    ~/.ivy2/shared/exampleorg/examplename/examplerev/jars/examplename.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== repo: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo.example.com/exampleorg/examplename/examplerev/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact exampleorg#examplename;examplerev!examplename.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo.example.com/exampleorg/examplename/examplerev/jars/examplename.jar
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: exampleorg#examplename;examplerev: not found
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
~/exampleproj/build.xml:123: impossible to resolve dependencies:
        resolve failed - see output for details
```

Running `ant -verbose resolve` as suggested by the warning prints the following line in the output:

```
[ivy:retrieve] don't use cache for exampleorg#examplename;examplerev: changing=true
```

How can I get Ivy to resolve `changing="true"` dependencies from the cache when offline, but continue to query the repository each build when online?

Comment: I gave an answer to that in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971517/how-do-i-tell-ivy4r-to-stay-offline

Comment: That's a second question. The first one has been answered

Comment: @Mark:  You're right.  I edited the question to remove the "how to conditionally set `ivy.cache.ttl.default=eternal`?" part because that is a separate issue.  But my original question -- how to resolve dependencies when offline -- is still unanswered.

Comment: it sounds like changing and ttl cannot be used together, it might be a good idea to ask this question on the [mailing list](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/mailing-lists.html)

Comment: This may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622640/ivycachepath-is-slow-how-to-avoid-doing-it-every-build-and-improve-ivy-cache

Answer (score 13):

oers has answered the question, but it's not obvious.

Try running your build setting the **ivy.cache.ttl.default** property from the command-line:

```
ant -Divy.cache.ttl.default=eternal build
```

Sources:

- [IVY-879](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-879)
- [Ivy mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-ivy-user/200905.mbox/%3Ce802d55e0905250229h7d6297bp9e054adee8a7431a@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I updated my answer with some of the information you gave here, to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, `-Divy.cache.ttl.default=eternal` doesn't work for me.  Please see the updated question.

Comment: @RichardHansen It looks like your build is not caching as expected...Could you post up your ivy settings? When I tested my ivy build it worked offline without any special settings :-(  (Also what version of ivy are you using?)

Comment: I figured out why `eternal` didn't work:  the dependency was marked `changing="true"`.  See updated question.