# Ant :: change the "depends" attribute of a target based on parameters passed

Tags: ant, ivy

I am using `Ant` with `Ivy` and so my `compile` task looks like:

```
<target name="compile" depends="prepare, retrieve" ..
```

where the `retrieve` task is used to resolve and fetch `Ivy` dependencies. So, since my `compile` task depends on the `retrieve` task, the resolving of `Ivy` dependencies is triggered with every compilation. Ditto for `run` since the `run` task depends on `compile`.

This wastes time so I would like to have a `dry-compile` which would not depend on the `Ivy` task.

The use case would be that if no `Ivy` dependency has changed I would be able to do an `ant dry-compile` or even an `ant dry-run` without triggering the `Ivy` resolving functionality.

Is there a way to do that in `Ant` without copy-pasting the targets to create variants with different `depends` attributes?

My **ivy.xml** file is:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
  <info organisation="foo" module="bar" status="integration"/>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.1"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

and the Ant `resolve` target (on which target `compile` depends) is:

```
<target name="test-ivy" description="Test ivy installation">
    <ivy:settings />
</target>

<target name="resolve" depends="test-ivy">
    <ivy:resolve/>
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" pattern="${ivylibs.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/> 
</target>
```

Comment: You have `retrieve`? You need to use `<ivy:resolve>` to resolve the dependencies. You should then use `<ivy:cachepath>` to create a path that you can use. This way, you don't need to retrieve the jars. You still need to resolve, but if you don't clean the Ivy cache, it shouldn't take too long. Are you doing a _clean_ with each build?

Comment: @DavidW. no, not clean on each build, resolve takes about 3-4 seconds which is too long if all I want to do is catch a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option is to switch off network based resolution and force ivy to use cached data.

See the following answer for more details:

- [Resolving Apache Ivy dependencies when offline/disconnected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629395/resolving-apache-ivy-dependencies-when-offline-disconnected/9630749#9630749)

Comment: Seems like like running "ant resolve" with or without -Divy.cache.ttl.default=eternal has no effect at all in my case.