# How do I configure Ivy to be used offline?

Tags: java, ivy

How do I force Ivy to work 'offline'; that is, to use only the caches?

The IvyDE plugin for Eclipse has this option. How do I do it from the command line/with ant? There is nothing obvious (that I can find) in the Ivy documentation (or at least that comes up in google searches).

[Maven has a -o option that does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233328/how-do-i-configure-maven-for-offline-development).

I'm assuming here that my local cache is fully populated with all the dependencies I need. I plug my laptop into the network at work, do a full build which populates my cache. Then I go home, and even though I have a network connection, I know Ivy can't reach my Ivy repositories, because they are private/internal at work. I don't want to wait for all the timeouts on connecting to the repo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell ivy4r to stay offline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971517/how-do-i-tell-ivy4r-to-stay-offline)

Comment: @oers You should consider adding the resolve tasks "useCachesOnly" attribute into your answer for completeness.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor will do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `useCachesOnly` property on [the `resolve` task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html) to `true`.